# Render a component from another class using function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a class like this:

```
class Blah extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleComponent = (event) => {

    let divid = event.target.getAttribute('id');

    if (divid === 'col') {
      // I want to render component by this condition
    } else if (divid === 'ro') {
      // or I want to render component by this condition
    } else {
      //or I want to render component by this condition
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div id = 'col' onClick={this.handleComponent}>Sheep</div>
        <div id = 'ro' onClick={this.handleComponent}>Cow</div>
        <div id = 'ball' onClick={this.handleComponent}>Dog</div>
        { I want to render my component here after click }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have another class written on top of this:

```
class Flow extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div style={{background:'somecolor'...blah blah}}>Clap</div>             
    );
  }
}
```

And I am Passing this by:

```
var foo = withStyles(styles)(Flow)
```

I have tried returning components but I am not getting anywhere.

I can use ternary operator but it still will render only one of two but I have three component have three design for each of them.

I want to render one of them to render on some condition as stated above.

If I use states that for toggle that will too have two components for render. Don't go on the code, this is made up, So any Ideas ? Fragments ? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: on click change the state called clicked and display component if state clicked to true

Comment: I am not checking for the true but specific value. please refer to code.

Comment: For this you need to understand the react better. you can keep all the conditional content inside render method with state value condition.  add state divID and change state divID onClick then render the component according to the condition. let me know if you need the answer

Comment: @Sandy See my answer, it explains how to render component conditionally depending on current state and user interaction/click.

Answer (score 0):

To render component by condition simply use `switch` statement.

In my example we use `state` to store `current` active component.

`renderMyComponent` method takes care of rendering one of three possible components.

`handleChange` method changes `current` state and triggers new `render` of `App` component.

---

This example use [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) plugin.

```
renderMyComponent = () => {
```

means autobind and is the same as using in constuctor method

```
this.renderMyComponent = this.renderMyComponent.bind(this);
```

**Working example:**

```js
const ComponentOne = () => <div>Hi, i am component one</div>;
const ComponentTwo = () => <div>Hi, i am component two</div>;
const ComponentThree = () => <div>Hi, i am component three</div>;


class App extends React.Component {
  state = { current: 0 }
  
  renderMyComponent = () => {
    // Our switch conditional render
    switch(this.state.current) {
      case 0:
        return <ComponentOne />;
      case 1:
        return <ComponentTwo />;
      case 2:
        return <ComponentThree />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
  
  handleChange = (event) => {
    // We are looking for data-trigger attribute
    // In this example we expect type number but trigger holds string
    // That's why we 'cast' to a number using Number()
    const current = Number(event.target.dataset.trigger);
    // Sets new state of current component and triggers new render
    this.setState({ current })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          Pick component to render
          <button 
            type="button" 
            data-trigger="0"
            onClick={this.handleChange}
          >
            Render 1
          </button>
          <button 
            type="button" 
            data-trigger="1" 
            onClick={this.handleChange}
          >
            Render 2
          </button>
          <button 
            type="button" 
            data-trigger="2" 
            onClick={this.handleChange}
          >
            Render 3
          </button>
        </div>
        {this.renderMyComponent()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Reviewing your code:**

You don't need constructor here.

```
...
constructor(props){
    super(props);

}
...
```